# php array_walk multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, hierarchy

I got three arrays with some kind of hierarchical predefined terms

```
array("fruits", "yellow", "pineapple");
array("fruits", "yellow", "lemon");
array("fruits", "red", "apple");
```

And I have an assoc array which has a kind of hierachy:

```
array('fruits'=>array('red'=>array('tomato')));
```

How can I push the terms of my three array at the right place that I get:

```
array('fruits'=>array('yellow'=>array('pineapple','lemon'),'red'=>array('tomato','apple')));
```

Do I use array_walk? Or array_walk_recursive? 
What should I use?

Best, Joerg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You convert each fruit to a nested array, then you merge using [array_merge_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

Here a working example ([also on Codepad](http://codepad.org/EwyrjwdU)):

```
$fruits = array(
  array("fruits", "yellow", "pineapple"),
  array("fruits", "yellow", "lemon"),
  array("fruits", "red", "apple"),
  array("fruits", "red", "tomato"),
);

// Convert array to nested array
function nest($leaf)
{
  if (count($leaf) > 1)
  {
    $key = array_shift($leaf);

    return array($key => nest($leaf));
  }
  else
  {
    return $leaf;
  }
}

$tree = array();

foreach($fruits as $fruit)
{
  // Convert each fruit to a nested array and merge recursively
  $tree = array_merge_recursive($tree, nest($fruit));
}

print_r($tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "yellow", "pineapple");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "yellow", "lemon");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "red", "apple");

foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
  $multifruit[$fruit[0]][$fruit[1]][] = $fruit[2];
}

print_r($multifruit);

/* yields:
Array
(
    [fruits] => Array
        (
            [yellow] => Array
                (
                    [0] => pineapple
                    [1] => lemon
                )

            [red] => Array
                (
                    [0] => apple
                )

        )

)
*/
```

Does exactly what you want. The last `[]` on the left side of the assignment appends the right side rather than overwriting any existing value if any exists.

Comment: My only problem with this answer is that it is not general enough to handle longer or shorter arrays. What if you feed it a `array('fruit','yellow','apple','granny smith')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$fruits[] = array("fruits", "yellow", "pineapple");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "yellow", "lemon");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "red", "apple");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "blue", "small","blueberry");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "blue", "bluefruit");
$fruits[] = array("fruits", "multicolor-fruit");

function deeper(&$multifruit, $fruit) {
    if (count($fruit)>2) {
        $shifted = array_shift($fruit);
        deeper($multifruit[$shifted], $fruit);
        return $multifruit;
    } else {
        return $multifruit[$fruit[0]][] = $fruit[1];
    }   
}   

foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
   deeper($multifruit, $fruit);
}   

print_r($multifruit);
?>
```

Here you go with a more general solution of your problem. It took me a while so I hope you appreciate it :)